# How to get Firebase parent in Android?

Tags: android, firebase

I have some data that's set up similar to this:

```
Users
-1
--name:Tom
--city:NYC
-2
--name:Dick
--city:LA
-3
--name:Harry
--city:Boston
```

I'm displaying the "name" fields in an Android app using a listview, then setting an on click listener to open up another page with more details. Right now, I'm just passing the position of the clicked item and adding 1 to get the correct parent node to insert into the reference for the clicked Firebase data set. This works fine, but if I want to add more sets in the future, I have to insert it in the proper place and renumber everything so that it all stays in order.

Is there a way to get the parent of the particular item I clicked on? I know Firebase has the `getParent()` method, but I can't figure out how to use it. `getKey()` might work, too, but again, I don't know how to use it. I can get the key for the reference, but that just returns "Users", as expected. I don't know how to tell Firebase I'm only looking for the key of that one particular child.

Comment: You seem to have code that doesn't work. Instead of asking us to post our code, the common approach on Stack Overflow is that you post your code and we tell you how to change that.

Comment: Trying `String itemParent = fbMembersRef.getParent().child("name").equalTo(clickedName).toString();` just makes a string that says com.firebase.client.Query@cf201c3, and that changes with repeated clicks on the same item. (`clickedName` is just the name text pulled from the TextView of the clicked item in the list). Trying `getKey()` in there instead of `getParent()` just makes a string that says "name". In the Android API reference, there's no documentation on how to use either `getParent()` or `getKey()`.

Comment: A workaround I found is to use a unique id as the node's name, instead of just adding 1 for each new set. Then I can add that id as one of the pieces of data in the set, retrieve it and add it to the Firebase path in the new activity. That's a workable option, I suppose.